# No implementation found for method getDatabasesPath

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sqflite

I saw that lot of people had a similar problem. However, so far I couldn't find a solution.
I'm building an Android app where I have implemented some bluetooth functionality. What I'm trying to do at the moment is to create a database to store configurations for bluetooth device. For this I'm using `sqflite` and `path` plugins. After the implementation I'm receiving the following error:
`[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite)`

My open database function:

```
    Database _database = await openDatabase(
      join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'dataset.db'),
      onCreate: (db, version) {
        return db.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE datasets(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, dataset TEXT)"
        );
      },
      version: 1,
    );
    return _database;
  }
```

Comment: from it's native code on android in sqlite which is getDatabasesPath is missing so the function for that will be no implementation will occur so. have you tried to flutter clean then after flutter pub get. its on the package itself. Also the repo for that is free anyways you can create an issue for that. I do sometimes encounter like this from other packages.

Comment: yes, I did. I did it few times. Also tried invalidating Android Studio cache, removing Flutter cache, different versions of sqflite. So far nothing worked :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I figured it out. The problem was within GeneratedRegistrantPlugin. Normally it should register all the Flutter plugins coming to native platform. However, in my case there was nothing(it is generated during *flutter pub get*). After the investigation I removed unnecessary folder example from my project and it finally allowed GeneratedRegistrantPlugin to generate correctly.